# Node-MySQL - Escaping in Query() Method vs Mysql.Escape() / Mysql.EscapeId()

Tags: node.js, express, node-mysql

I am currently using the [node-mysql](https://github.com/felixge/node-mysql) library to connect my application to a MySQL instance.  After reading some other StackOverflow questions and articles I found, it sounds like node-mysql automatically escapes unsafe characters every time the `query()` method is called.  But on some code snippets, I also see `mysql.escape()` and `mysql.escapeId()` being called within the `query()` method.

It seems like that while `query()` automatically escapes some dangerous characters, you should still call `mysql.escape()` and `mysql.escapeId()` to escape other dangerous characters.

Is this correct?  If so, what kind of SQL injection attacks are automatically protected against by the `query()` method and what kind of SQL injection attacks are protected by calling `mysql.escape()` and `mysql.escapeId()`?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

No, `query()` does not automatically escape unsafe characters.

To safely escape values, you need to use `mysql.escape()`/`mysql.escapeId()` or use `?` placeholders as described here:

https://github.com/felixge/node-mysql#escaping-query-values

```
connection.query('SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = ?', [userId], function(err, results) {
  // ...
});
```

Comment: So if you're using placeholders the strings are automatically escaped?

Comment: I know it's late but, yes. Using placeholders automatically escapes the strings. Internally it's still using escape btw

Answer (score 0):

And this is how to escape INSERT VALUES() because all examples everywhere is with ?  for SET method, for escaping VALUES(Data,Data) that are separate by comma you can use template string. Also escape command when data are empty its replace by NULL

```
(`INSERT INTO data VALUES (NULL,${c.escape(data.Name)},${c.escape(data.age)},${c.escape(data.emptystring)})`,
//INSERT INTO data VALUES (NULL,'Adam',24,NULL})
```